# Lightsail AWS Node.js start forever

Tags: node.js, amazon-lightsail, vapid

I'm experimenting with Vapid CMS and I want to upload a new site to my Amazon Lightsail server. Vapid is dependent on Node.js and I was able to download Vapid to my account and get everything set up with the static IP address I have through AWS.

The way Vapid works is that once you're in the root folder you call vapid start . to start the server and see your site/get access to the dashboard.  I have it set up so that the static IP address of the AWS server redirects to the default http://localhost:3000 that is activated when you start up Vapid.

The main problem I'm having is that the Vapid site doesn't stay active very long. If I exit out of the AWS terminal after stating Vapid, in a few minutes the site goes to "Service Unavailable." Is there a way to keep that sucker running forever so that my site stays up until the end of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Systemd to keep your process running. It will ensure that Vapid CMS process is running and restarts it after crash.

Check one these tutorials:

- Systemd with NodeJS https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/
- Systemd+PM2 with Valid CMS https://mallinson.ca/posts/12/vapid-on-digital-ocean

Answer (score 1):

While Systemd or PM2 can be used to keep the node process running if it crashes, this will not prevent it from closing if you are running these commands from a terminal using ssh to access the server and then exit the terminal.

This is because the terminal will send the signal hang up command (`SIGHUP`) to the process when it's closed.

The easiest way to prevent this is using the `nohup` command. It's designed for the purpose. Instead of `vapid start` run:

`nohup vapid start &`

The `nohup` command will prevent the terminal from sending the `SIGHUP` when exiting. The `&` command will run the process in the background, allowing you to run additional terminal commands (such as exiting).

Comment: I didn't try this method, but if I run into the issue again I'll try it out!